# layout issues with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm getting closer but still have a couple of problems laying out some css. See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgyB/5/).

1. When you click on a button the info message appears under the video as desired, but it also moves the div `#help-tips-ipad` down. It should stay where it is.
2. For some reason the length of the info message is longer than the video player. I want it to be the same size. I don't understand as I explicitly have it set to `width: 320px`?

Same code as the fiddle:

```
<p><div id="player-ipad">Video player here</div></p>
<div id="quote"><p></p></div>
<div id="help-tips-ipad">
<p>Read our Guide</p>
<p>Visit our Support Forum and ask a question</p>
<ul>
<li>Text.</li>
<li>More text.</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="prettytablediv-ipad">
<p>
<table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Camera Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" value="button1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" value="button2">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#prettytablediv-ipad {
  width: 550px;
  float: left;            
}
#help-tips-ipad {
  width: 320px;
  float: right;

}
#player-ipad {
  width:320px;
  height:240px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".play", function() {
$('#quote p').html("INFO").css({'border': '1px solid', 'margin': '10px 0px', 'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': '10px center', 'color': '#00529B', 'background-color': '#BDE5F8', 'width': '320px','display': 'block','clear': 'left'});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within your question.  External links are great but if they cease to exist, your question should still be useful to others.

Comment: Where is the info message supposed to go when the button is clicked? Can you make a mockup of some sort?

Comment: @millimoose right under the video player (or the mock up in the fiddle) and between the video player and table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a float-wrapping issue - the `<div id="quote">` element is 100% width, you need to float it left or the subsequent elements will be forced below it. Really, you should add that AFTER `<div id="help-tips-ipad">` or else the float won't do what you expect.
2. The padding is added AFTER the width is applied - you need to compensate for that when setting a fixed width like you've done.

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgyB/11/) for an example.

Comment: Strange my div for the table is now floating on the right when I implement this. Tried to follow your fiddle which works but still pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are using 320px as the width, which is then getting padding added onto this value.

```
{ 'padding' : '15px 10px 15px 50px' }
```

The browser will take 320px, and add on 10px + 50px (left and right padding) which will result in a total width of **380px**;

You need to take **60px** off your width, which then becomes **260px**.

You then need to take into account the border too, which is 10px (5+5) on your bigger box, minus the 2 x 1px on your generated box = Add another 8px

new total width = **268px;**

In short: **Total width of your box is Width + left border width + right border width + left padding + right padding**.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot wrap divs with paragraphs (

   tag). Also the floated paragraph has 100% width, it should have the same width as the div above him (it's even better to wrap both with the same div)
2. The padding is added after width, and the total width is the sum of both so it's wider than you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` to `270px`

```
$(document).on("click", ".play", function() {

$('#quote p').html("INFO").css({
    'border': '1px solid', 
    'margin': '10px 0px', 
    'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px', 
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 
    'background-position': '10px center', 
    'color': '#00529B', 
    'background-color': '#BDE5F8', 
    'width': '270px',
    'display': 'block',
    'clear': 'left'}); 
});
```

​